# My Router/AP rebooted and now Windows computers can't connect to the 5GHz SSID

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, wireless-access-point

Today I unplugged my Synology WRX560 and after I plugged it back in all the devices in my house connected to the router again except for my Windows computers. I have Smart Connect turned off, so I have two SSID, one for 5GHz. Several devices connected back to the 5GHz network, including my phone which is sitting right next to my computer. In fact, I can walk to all three computers and have strong 5GHz signal. So, it isn't a signal strength problem.

My Windows computers can connect to the 2.4GHz network.

I tried connecting to a Hidden Network (which this SSID isn't) and I just get a generic error: "Can't connect to this network". (Shame on Windows for thinking this is an acceptable error message.)

I tried adjusting the settings for the 5GHz network to turn off all the advanced check marks.

I tried narrowing the bandwidth to 20MHz and setting the wireless mode to all the different options.

I tried unchecking all the DFS and 5.9GHz stuff.

I tried creating a new network, both with and without Smart Connect. When Smart Connect is on, the computers still only connect at 2.4GHz.

Any help at all would be very much appreciated. I haven't had this router too long, but I've loved it so far and would like to keep using it, but this just won't work for me. My Googling has led me nowhere. Every page I go to seems to insist that I need to "update my driver" or something like that. It can't be that three of my machines (Surface Book 3, Surface Book 2, Dell XPS) all had the same problem at the same time. One of them is a work computer for which I don't have admin rights or control drivers for, so I'm 90% disinclined to think this has anything to do with Windows. The counterpoint is that my phones are fine on the 5GHz network (Samsung S23+).

**UPDATE**: After trying Nirsoft's WiFi Info View on one of the computers, I see the the SSID that my phone is connected to doesn't show at all, not even by MAC address. I'm using Network Signal Info to get the network info that my phone is seeing. I should also add that I can see several other 5GHz networks and other ax networks. I see many other networks at 80MHz channel width too.

**UPDATE**: It turns out it was all the computers in my house. My Windows computers, my Macs, my Apple TV, pretty much every device stopped working on my 5GHz network except for my phones. My phones (S23+) showed they were connected just fine on band 171.

Comment: Try Nirsoft's WiFi Info View, https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wifi_information_view.html . **If** the WiFi car on the Windows PC can connect, then the 5 GHz connection will be displayed. Right-click on it and select *Connect Selected Access Point*. You can also make a Desktop Shortcut to that connection -- often, after emerging from hibernation, one Windows PC I have loses connectivity, but the shortcut reconnects as wanted.

Comment: Thanks @DrMoishePippik. I've updated my issue to reflect findings from your suggestion.

Comment: This is usually due to the router's wireless implementation/settings, or WiFi adapter settings in Windows. **Router WiFi Radio:** Set to an actual channel for 5Ghz, not Auto _(157 usually works the best in the US)_; Channel width should be VHT _(80Mhz)_, or if supporting 160MHz, 160MHz; WMM should be enabled. If it's the wireless implementation on the router, setting different passphrases for the 2Ghz and 5Ghz networks is usually the fix _(this has caveats for other devices, so it's often easier to create a seperate 5GHz AP and assign it to the LAN firewall zone)_. _(Cont'd...)_

Comment: _(Cont'd...)_ **Windows WiFi Adapter:** `WinKey`+`R` → _Open:_ `ncpa.cpl` → Right-click on WiFi adapter → _Properties_ → _Configure..._ → _Advanced_ → This is where it varies from adapter to adapter: For an Intel WiFi adapter: _802.11n Channel Width for 5.2Ghz:_ Auto | _Ad Hoc QoS Mode:_ WMM enabled | _Fat Channel Intolerant:_ Disabled | _HT Mode:_ VHT Mode | _Preferred Band:_ 3. Prefer 5.2Ghz band | _Throughput Booster:_ Enabled | _Transmit Power:_ 5. Highest | _Wireless Mode:_ 1. 802.11a

Comment: @JW0914, I can't thank you enough. Please post this as an answer. The router selected 171 and then 175, neither of which apparently my computers can see. I forced it to channel 48 and everything is working again. I'd love to know how to get the Synology router to only select from certain channels when doing DFS.

Comment: Glad you solved the issue. BTW, some routers can wok simultaneously on more than one band at a time. The one I have in use now has *four* SSID's, two at 2.4 GHz, and two at 5 GHz. That lets the connected device choose the band -- low frequency for better penetration, high for faster throughput.

Comment: @cjbarth I think you should write your own Answer since it came down to the Synology AP choosing newly-made-available-by-the-regulatory-agencies, not-widely-supported channels even when you had seemingly told it not to. Your real fix was what you did in the Synology AP's settings, not anything you did on the Windows client side. BTW, the DFS channel rules require the AP to select a channel at random, without any weighting (can't prefer any particular DFS channels over any others).

Comment: @DrMoishePippik, which router do you have? The one only has two radios, so I can have multiple SSIDs, but can only have two radio configurations (channels, n, ac, ax, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@JW0914 wrote in a comment above:

> This is usually due to the router's wireless implementation/settings,
> or WiFi adapter settings in Windows.
>
> ### Router WiFi Radio
>
> Set to an actual channel for 5Ghz, not Auto (157 usually works the best in the US); Channel width should be VHT
> (80Mhz), or if supporting 160MHz, 160MHz; WMM should be enabled. If
> it's the wireless implementation on the router, setting different
> passphrases for the 2Ghz and 5Ghz networks is usually the fix (this
> has caveats for other devices, so it's often easier to create a
> separate 5GHz AP and assign it to the LAN firewall zone).
>
> ### Windows WiFi Adapter
>
> <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd> → Open: `ncpa.cpl` → Right-click on WiFi adapter → Properties → Configure... →
> Advanced → This is where it varies from adapter to adapter.
>
> #### For an Intel WiFi adapter
>
> - 802.11n Channel Width for 5.2Ghz: Auto
> - Ad Hoc QoS Mode: WMM enabled
> - Fat Channel Intolerant: Disabled
> - HT Mode: VHT Mode
> - Preferred Band: 3. Prefer 5.2Ghz band
> - Throughput Booster: Enabled
> - Transmit Power: 5. Highest
> - Wireless Mode: 1. 802.11a

## Solution

After reading the comments and looking closely at some references at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WLAN_channels) and [this](https://dongknows.com/5-9ghz-wi-fi-6-explained-how-unii-4-can-be-exciting/) blog post, it seems my problem was that the computers at my home didn't support U-NII-4 (5.9GHz), but my router did. So, when my router DFS switched to that band, all my computers lost their connections. I had to not only disable the 5.9GHz band, but force my router down to a lower band (I choose U-NII-1 for best compatibility).

Disabling that feature on a Synology router apparently only has an effect on switching *to* those bands, not being on those bands or otherwise having those bands available. Following the first bit of advice to manually pick a band on my router immediately fixed this issue leading to this discovery.